# Spring Batch ItemReader - Maintain pointer or remove item from List?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I just started working with Spring Batch and was wondering what the best practice is for maintaining the list of items to read in ItemReader. The example I saw has something like:

```
private static List<Resource> items = new LinkedList<Resource>();
private static int index = 0;

private void initialize(){
    items.add(new Resource());
}
```

and

```
public Model read(){
   if(index < items.size())
      return new Model(items.get(index++));
   return null;
}
```

What are the benefits of this approach vs not using an index and simply shortening the list? E.g.:

```
public Model read(){
   if(items.size() > 0)
      return new Model(items.remove(0));
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of following disadvantages in the 2nd approach:

- `items` doesn't remain usable after one iteration on it.
- It might be slower, depending on the concrete type of the `List`. If it were a `LinkedList`, things should be fine. But for an `ArrayList`, lot of elements will be shifted on every `remove`.